# How can I create React route without rendering any component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-router

Greeting from my side..
I am very new to react and I have one functionality that I create a one unique route in react and on that url hit I need to call a api which do some work for me.

According to me I create a empty component and in return I am returning React Fragment only
and on the useEffect of that component I try to hit my api .

but the problem is that my api hits two times but I need to api hit only once and redirect to some path.

```
useEffect(()=>{
        const verifyEmail = () =>{
            const url = "myurl"
            const config = {
                headers:{
                    "secret_key":"mykey",
                    "Content-Type":"application/json",
                }
            }
            const data = {
                id:id
            }
            axios.post(url,data,config)
            .then(
                (response) =>{
                    console.log(response.data)
                    const result = JSON.parse(response.data)
                    if(result.code === 1){
                        alert(result.message)
                        navigate("/")
                    }else{
                        alert(result.message)
                        navigate("/")
                    }
                }
            ).catch((error) =>{
                alert("something went wrong")
            })
        }
        verifyEmail()
    return () => {
            cleanup
        }
    },[])
```

How can I achieve it ?
or is I am doing something wrong ?
guide me

Comment: We can't really help diagnose or debug code we can't see. Please update your post to include a [mcve] for the relevant code you are working with and have an issue using.

Comment: Are you rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component? Is this why the mounting `useEffect` hook is called twice?

Comment: yes I am rendering my component in Strict mode

Comment: how can I stop it ?

Comment: I see. You should return a cleanup function from the `useEffect` hook to cancel any in-flight network requests.

Comment: I have edited my code please see it .Is it right ?